# Regex on output Huawei Python

Tags: python, regex

The output in my python script is the following:

GigabitEthernet0/0/0 current state : DOWN

Description:HUAWEI, AR Series, GigabitEthernet0/0/0 Interface

Discard:                  0,  Total Error:                 0

Discard:                  0,  Total Error:                 0

Now, i want to regex function on multiple lines.

In fact, i want to have the interface and next to the interface the 'Discard' text with approx counter which is all 0.

To list up the interface I found a way, but the multiple lines are difficult for me..

Here is what i have got

```
\w+/[0-9]/[0-9]
```

After that I use the join function to list all interfaces up in the end. How can I add next to the interface the discard value with text discard?

Comment: Try to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please give a sample output according to your example and show your corrent code as complement